# Удаленность сторон куба от плоскости проекции

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, графика, 3d, геометрия

Дано:

1. [Система координат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKXyI.png)
2. Куб вращается вокруг своего центра по всем трем осям.
3. Угол поворота заранее не известен.
4. Параллельная проекция считается по формуле:

   > x`` = x;
   >
   > y`` = y + z / 4;
5. В единицу времени отображаются только 3 ближних к плоскости проекции грани.

Вопрос:

**Как определить, какие из граней ближние?**

Делаю таким образом: беру попарно грани правую и левую, переднюю и заднюю, верхнюю и нижнюю, затем вычисляю дальнюю и ближнюю точки по оси (Z), составляю уравнение прямой, беру вторую по удаленности точку по оси (Z), и подставляю в это уравнение - так определяю наклон плоскости. Исходя из этого выбираю какая из 2х граней ближе к плоскости проекции.

Такой код не работает.

```js
'use strict';

    var figures;

    var figure_111 = {

        //╔═══╗
        //║   ║
        //╚═══╝

        figureType: 5,
        figurePositionY: 1,
        figurePositionX: 1,
        figurePositionZ: 1,
        shape: [
            [[5]]
        ],
        rotateZ: function () {
            this.shape = rotateZ(this.shape);
            this.figurePositionZ = changePosition(this.figurePositionZ);
        }
    };

    function initAnimation() {
        figures = [
            figure_111
        ];

        // Запускаем падение
        figureStartsFalling();
    }

    // Текущая фигура
    var currentFigure;

    // Размер фигуры
    var size = 30;

    // Объект на основании фигуры
    var fallingObject;

    // Цвет фигуры
    var figureColor;

    // Центр фигуры
    var t0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('animation');
    var canvas_context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Сместим центр оси (Х) в середину поля
    canvas_context.translate(canvas.width / 2, 0);

    var doTenTimes;

    function figureStartsFalling() {
        doTenTimes = 30;
        // Переопределяем текущую фигуру
        currentFigure = figures[Math.floor(Math.random() * figures.length)];

        // Получим цвет текущей фигуры
        figureColor = 'rgb(0,200,0)';

        // Высота фигуры
        var figureHeight = currentFigure.shape.length;

        // Строим 3Д объект на основании фигуры
        fallingObject = [];
        var cube = [];
        var side = [];

        for (var y = currentFigure.shape.length - 1; y > -1; y--) {
            for (var x = 0; x < currentFigure.shape[0].length; x++) {
                for (var z = 0; z < currentFigure.shape[0][0].length; z++) {
                    // Для каждой клеточки создаем кубик с 5 гранями
                    cube = [];
                    if (currentFigure.shape[y][x][z] != 0) {
                        // Левая стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'left'}
                        ];
                        // Центральная координата, нужна для расчета удаленности по осям (X) и (Z)
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если левее чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (x > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x - 1][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Правая стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'right'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если правее чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (x + 1 < currentFigure.shape[0].length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x + 1][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Задняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'rear'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если сзади чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (z > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x][z - 1] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Передняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {m:'front'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если впереди чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (z + 1 < currentFigure.shape[0][0].length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x][z + 1] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Верхняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'top'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если сверху чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (y > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y - 1][x][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Нижняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'bottom'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если снизу чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (y + 1 < currentFigure.shape.length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y + 1][x][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);
                        fallingObject.push(cube);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Определим центр фигуры
        t0 = {
            y:currentFigure.shape.length / 2 * size - figureHeight*size,
            x:currentFigure.shape[0].length / 2 * size,
            z:currentFigure.shape[0][0].length / 2 * size
        };

        // Запускаем падение
        setTimeout(figureFalls, 100);
    }

    // Угол поворота, не изменяется
    var deg = 1;

    // Текущая проекция
    var arrProj;

    var tempArr;

    function figureFalls() {

        // Сначала очистим экран - закрасим белым цветом
        clearScreen(canvas, canvas_context, 'rgb(255,255,255)');

        // Изменяем положение текущей фигуры
        for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    // Повернем фигуру на угол
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeY(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeX(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeZ(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    // и опустим вниз на 1px
                    fallingObject[i][j][k].y += 1;
                }
                // Пересчитаем центральную координату плоскости
                fallingObject[i][j][4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(fallingObject[i][j]);
            }
            doTenTimes -= 1;
            // Пересчитаем центральную координату кубика
            fallingObject[i][6] = getCubecentralCoordinate(fallingObject[i]);
            // Если кубик ушел слишком далеко - удаляем кубик
            if (fallingObject[i][6].y > canvas.height) {
                fallingObject.splice(i, 1);
                i -=1;
            }
        }

        // Центр фигуры тоже опускается
        t0.y += 1;

        // Сортируем кубики по удаленности от начала координат по (X) и (Z)
        var exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            exit = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length - 1; i++) {
                if (fallingObject[i][6].z > fallingObject[i + 1][6].z) {
                    tempArr = fallingObject[i];
                    fallingObject[i] = fallingObject[i + 1];
                    fallingObject[i + 1] = tempArr;
                    exit = false;
                } else if (fallingObject[i][6].z == fallingObject[i + 1][6].z) {
                    if (fallingObject[i][6].x > fallingObject[i + 1][6].x) {
                        tempArr = fallingObject[i];
                        fallingObject[i] = fallingObject[i + 1];
                        fallingObject[i + 1] = tempArr;
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Отрисовываем фигуру
        for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length; i++) {
            // Получим параллельную проекцию
            arrProj = getParallelProjection(fallingObject[i]);
            // Нарисуем параллельную проекцию
            fillFigure(canvas_context, arrProj, figureColor);
        }

        // Если в видимой области еще есть кубики -
        // переходим на следующий шаг
        if (fallingObject.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(figureFalls, 100);
        }
        // иначе начинаем заново с новой фигурой
        else {
            setTimeout(figureStartsFalling, 100);
        }
    }

    // Получим центральную координату плоскости
    // для расчета удаленности от задней стенки
    function getSidecentralCoordinate(side) {

        var centralCoordinate = {x:0, y:0, z:0};

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            centralCoordinate.x += side[i].x;
            centralCoordinate.y += side[i].y;
            centralCoordinate.z += side[i].z;
        }

        centralCoordinate.x = centralCoordinate.x / 4;
        centralCoordinate.y = centralCoordinate.y / 4;
        centralCoordinate.z = centralCoordinate.z / 4;

        centralCoordinate.m = side[4].m;

        return centralCoordinate;
    }

    // Получим центральную координату кубика
    // для расчета удаленности от начала координат
    function getCubecentralCoordinate(side) {
        var centralCoordinate = {x:0, y:0, z:0};

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            centralCoordinate.x += side[i][4].x;
            centralCoordinate.y += side[i][4].y;
            centralCoordinate.z += side[i][4].z;
        }

        centralCoordinate.x = centralCoordinate.x / 6;
        centralCoordinate.y = centralCoordinate.y / 6;
        centralCoordinate.z = centralCoordinate.z / 6;

        return centralCoordinate;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (Y)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeY(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t0.x + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.z - t0.z) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.y = t.y;
        t_new.z = t0.z + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.z - t0.z) * Math.cos(rad);

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (X)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeX(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t.x;
        t_new.y = t0.y + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.z - t0.z) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.z = t0.z + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.z - t0.z) * Math.cos(rad);

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (Z)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeZ(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t0.x + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.y - t0.y) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.y = t0.y + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.cos(rad);
        t_new.z = t.z;

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Закрашиваем весь экран определенным цветом
    function clearScreen(canvas, context, color) {
        context.fillStyle = color;

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillRect(- canvas.width / 2, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    // Получаем параллельную проекцию кубика на плоскость экрана
    function getParallelProjection(arr) {

        var i, j, k;

        var arr_new = [];

        // Попарно работаем с гранями
        arr_new[0] = getSideParallelProjection(arr[0], arr[1], arr[6]); // Левая и правая
        arr_new[1] = getSideParallelProjection(arr[2], arr[3], arr[6]); // Задняя и передняя
        arr_new[2] = getSideParallelProjection(arr[4], arr[5], arr[6]); // Верхняя и нижняя

        return arr_new;
    }

    // Параллельная проекция грани
    function getSideParallelProjection(side1, side2, cubeCenter) {

        // Сначала выясним какая пара нам попалась
        var centralProjection1 = getPointParallelProjection(side1[4]);
        var centralProjection2 = getPointParallelProjection(side2[4]);

        var coordinate = {
            x:Math.abs(side1[4].x - side2[4].x),
            y:Math.abs(side1[4].y - side2[4].y),
            z:Math.abs(side1[4].z - side2[4].z)};

        var i;

    // Найдем дальнюю (1) и ближнюю (2) от экрана точки
    // по оси (Z) и посчитаем их проекции
    var point1 = {z:10000},
        point2 = {z:-10000},
        point3 = {z:10000};

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (point1.z > side1[i].z) {
            point1 = side1[i];
        }
        if (point1.z == side1[i].z
            && point1.x > side1[i].x) {
            point1 = side1[i];
        }
        if (point1.z == side1[i].z
            && point1.x == side1[i].x
            && point1.y < side1[i].y) {
            point1 = side1[i];
        }
        if (point2.z < side1[i].z) {
            point2 = side1[i];
        }
        if (point2.z == side1[i].z
            && point2.x < side1[i].x) {
            point2 = side1[i];
        }
        if (point2.z == side1[i].z
            && point2.x == side1[i].x
            && point2.y > side1[i].y) {
            point2 = side1[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (point3.z > side1[i].z
            && point1 != side1[i]) {
            point3 = side1[i];
        }
        if (point3.z == side1[i].z
            && point3.x > side1[i].x
            && point1 != side1[i]) {
            point3 = side1[i];
        }
        if (point3.z == side1[i].z
            && point3.x == side1[i].x
            && point3.y < side1[i].y
            && point1 != side1[i]) {
            point3 = side1[i];
        }
    }

 var direction = (point3.x - point1.x) / (point2.x - point1.x)
                            - (point3.y - point1.y) / (point2.y - point1.y);
        var projection = [];

        // (X) Правая и левая грани
        if (coordinate.x > coordinate.y && coordinate.x > coordinate.z) {

            point1 = getPointParallelProjection(point1);
            point2 = getPointParallelProjection(point2);
            point3 = getPointParallelProjection(point3);

            var direction = (point3.x - point1.x) / (point2.x - point1.x)
                - (point3.y - point1.y) / (point2.y - point1.y);

            var selected;

            if (point1.x >= point2.x) {
                if (centralProjection1.x >= centralProjection2.x) {
                    selected = side1;
                } else {
                    selected = side2;
                }
            } else {
                if (centralProjection1.x <= centralProjection2.x) {
                    selected = side1;
                } else {
                    selected = side2;
                }
            }

            if (selected.length < 6) {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    projection[i] = getPointParallelProjection(selected[i]);
                }
                projection[4] = 'rgb(200,200,0)';
            }
        }

        // (Z) Передняя и задняя грани
        else if (coordinate.z > coordinate.x && coordinate.z > coordinate.y) {

            var selected;

            if (point1.x >= point2.x && direction < 0) {
                if (centralProjection1.x >= centralProjection2.x) {
                    selected = side1;
                } else {
                    selected = side2;
                }
            } else {
                if (centralProjection1.x <= centralProjection2.x) {
                    selected = side1;
                } else {
                    selected = side2;
                }
            }

            if (selected.length < 6) {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    projection[i] = getPointParallelProjection(selected[i]);
                }
                projection[4] = 'rgb(200,0,0)';
            }
        }

        // (Y) Верхняя и нижняя грани
        else {

            var selected;

            if (point1.y <= point2.y) {
                if (centralProjection1.y <= centralProjection2.y) {
                    selected = side1;
                } else {
                    selected = side2;
                }
            } else {
                if (centralProjection1.y >= centralProjection2.y) {
                    selected = side1;
                } else {
                    selected = side2;
                }
            }

            if (selected.length < 6) {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    projection[i] = getPointParallelProjection(selected[i]);
                }
                projection[4] = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            }
        }

        return projection;
    }
    // Параллельная проекция точки
    function getPointParallelProjection(point) {
        return {
            x:point.x,
            y:point.y + point.z / 4};
//        return {
//            x:point.x + point.z * Math.cos(Math.PI * 3 / 4) / 2,
//            y:point.y + point.z * Math.sin(Math.PI * 3 / 4) / 2};
    }

    // Рисуем фигуру по точкам из массива
    function fillFigure(context, arr, color) {
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        context.fillStyle = color;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            context.beginPath();
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][4] != undefined) {
                    context.fillStyle = arr[i][4];
                } else {
                    context.fillStyle = color;
                }
                if (j == 0) {
                    context.moveTo(arr[i][j].x, arr[i][j].y);
                } else {
                    context.lineTo(arr[i][j].x, arr[i][j].y);
                }
            }
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    // Запускаем наш скрипт
    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(initAnimation, 200);
    };
```

```html
<canvas id="animation" width="300" height="300">
    <p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает Canvas</p>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Слова ничего не значат. Покажите мне код. (c) Линус Торвальдс

Challenge accepted. [Фиддл](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqghevgv/)

```js
'use strict';

    var figures;

    var figure_111 = {

        //╔═══╗
        //║   ║
        //╚═══╝

        figureType: 5,
        figurePositionY: 1,
        figurePositionX: 1,
        figurePositionZ: 1,
        shape: [
            [[5]]
        ],
        rotateZ: function () {
            this.shape = rotateZ(this.shape);
            this.figurePositionZ = changePosition(this.figurePositionZ);
        }
    };

    function initAnimation() {
        figures = [
            figure_111
        ];

        // Запускаем падение
        figureStartsFalling();
    }

    // Текущая фигура
    var currentFigure;

    // Размер фигуры
    var size = 70;

    // Объект на основании фигуры
    var fallingObject;

    // Цвет фигуры
    var figureColor;

    // Центр фигуры
    var t0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('animation');
    var canvas_context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Сместим центр оси (Х) в середину поля
    canvas_context.translate(canvas.width / 2, 0);

    var doTenTimes;

    function figureStartsFalling() {
        doTenTimes = 30;
        // Переопределяем текущую фигуру
        currentFigure = figures[Math.floor(Math.random() * figures.length)];

        // Получим цвет текущей фигуры
        figureColor = 'rgb(0,200,0)';

        // Высота фигуры
        var figureHeight = currentFigure.shape.length;

        // Строим 3Д объект на основании фигуры
        fallingObject = [];
        var cube = [];
        var side = [];

        for (var y = currentFigure.shape.length - 1; y > -1; y--) {
            for (var x = 0; x < currentFigure.shape[0].length; x++) {
                for (var z = 0; z < currentFigure.shape[0][0].length; z++) {
                    // Для каждой клеточки создаем кубик с 5 гранями
                    cube = [];
                    if (currentFigure.shape[y][x][z] != 0) {
                        // Левая стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'left'}
                        ];
                        // Центральная координата, нужна для расчета удаленности по осям (X) и (Z)
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если левее чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (x > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x - 1][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Правая стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {m:'right'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если правее чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (x + 1 < currentFigure.shape[0].length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x + 1][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Задняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'rear'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если сзади чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (z > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x][z - 1] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Передняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {m:'front'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если впереди чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (z + 1 < currentFigure.shape[0][0].length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x][z + 1] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Верхняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {m:'top'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если сверху чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (y > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y - 1][x][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Нижняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'bottom'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если снизу чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (y + 1 < currentFigure.shape.length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y + 1][x][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);
                        fallingObject.push(cube);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Определим центр фигуры
        t0 = {
            y:currentFigure.shape.length / 2 * size - figureHeight*size,
            x:currentFigure.shape[0].length / 2 * size,
            z:currentFigure.shape[0][0].length / 2 * size
        };

        // Запускаем падение
        setTimeout(figureFalls, 100);
    }

    // Угол поворота, не изменяется
    var deg = 1;

    // Текущая проекция
    var arrProj;

    var tempArr;

    function figureFalls() {

        // Сначала очистим экран - закрасим белым цветом
        clearScreen(canvas, canvas_context, 'rgb(255,255,255)');

        // Изменяем положение текущей фигуры
        for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    // Повернем фигуру на угол
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeY(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeX(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeZ(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    // и опустим вниз на 1px
                    fallingObject[i][j][k].y += 1;
                }
                // Пересчитаем центральную координату плоскости
                fallingObject[i][j][4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(fallingObject[i][j]);
            }
            doTenTimes -= 1;
            // Пересчитаем центральную координату кубика
            fallingObject[i][6] = getCubecentralCoordinate(fallingObject[i]);
            // Если кубик ушел слишком далеко - удаляем кубик
            if (fallingObject[i][6].y > canvas.height) {
                fallingObject.splice(i, 1);
                i -=1;
            }
        }

        // Центр фигуры тоже опускается
        t0.y += 1;

        // Сортируем кубики по удаленности от начала координат по (X) и (Z)
        var exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            exit = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length - 1; i++) {
                if (fallingObject[i][6].z > fallingObject[i + 1][6].z) {
                    tempArr = fallingObject[i];
                    fallingObject[i] = fallingObject[i + 1];
                    fallingObject[i + 1] = tempArr;
                    exit = false;
                } else if (fallingObject[i][6].z == fallingObject[i + 1][6].z) {
                    if (fallingObject[i][6].x > fallingObject[i + 1][6].x) {
                        tempArr = fallingObject[i];
                        fallingObject[i] = fallingObject[i + 1];
                        fallingObject[i + 1] = tempArr;
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Отрисовываем фигуру
        for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length; i++) {
            // Получим параллельную проекцию
            arrProj = getParallelProjection(fallingObject[i]);
            // Нарисуем параллельную проекцию
            fillFigure(canvas_context, arrProj, figureColor);
        }

        // Если в видимой области еще есть кубики -
        // переходим на следующий шаг
        if (fallingObject.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(figureFalls, 100);
        }
        // иначе начинаем заново с новой фигурой
        else {
            setTimeout(figureStartsFalling, 100);
        }
    }

    // Получим центральную координату плоскости
    // для расчета удаленности от задней стенки
    function getSidecentralCoordinate(side) {

        var centralCoordinate = {x:0, y:0, z:0};

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            centralCoordinate.x += side[i].x;
            centralCoordinate.y += side[i].y;
            centralCoordinate.z += side[i].z;
        }

        centralCoordinate.x = centralCoordinate.x / 4;
        centralCoordinate.y = centralCoordinate.y / 4;
        centralCoordinate.z = centralCoordinate.z / 4;

        centralCoordinate.m = side[4].m;

        return centralCoordinate;
    }

    // Получим центральную координату кубика
    // для расчета удаленности от начала координат
    function getCubecentralCoordinate(side) {
        var centralCoordinate = {x:0, y:0, z:0};

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            centralCoordinate.x += side[i][4].x;
            centralCoordinate.y += side[i][4].y;
            centralCoordinate.z += side[i][4].z;
        }

        centralCoordinate.x = centralCoordinate.x / 6;
        centralCoordinate.y = centralCoordinate.y / 6;
        centralCoordinate.z = centralCoordinate.z / 6;

        return centralCoordinate;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (Y)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeY(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t0.x + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.z - t0.z) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.y = t.y;
        t_new.z = t0.z + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.z - t0.z) * Math.cos(rad);

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (X)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeX(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t.x;
        t_new.y = t0.y + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.z - t0.z) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.z = t0.z + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.z - t0.z) * Math.cos(rad);

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (Z)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeZ(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t0.x + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.y - t0.y) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.y = t0.y + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.cos(rad);
        t_new.z = t.z;

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Закрашиваем весь экран определенным цветом
    function clearScreen(canvas, context, color) {
        context.fillStyle = color;

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillRect(- canvas.width / 2, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    // Получаем параллельную проекцию кубика на плоскость экрана
    function getParallelProjection(arr) {

        var i, j, k;

        var projected = [];
        var projection;

        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            projection = [];
            if (arr[i].length < 6) {
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    projection[j] = getPointParallelProjection(arr[i][j]);
                }
            }
            projected[i] = projection;
        }

        return projected.filter(isClockwise);
    }
 
 function isClockwise(point_array) {
  if (point_array.length < 3) return false;
  var p0 = point_array[0];
  var p1 = point_array[1];
  var p2 = point_array[2];
  return (p1.x-p0.x)*(p2.y-p0.y) - (p2.x-p0.x)*(p1.y-p0.y) > 0;
 }

    // Параллельная проекция точки
    function getPointParallelProjection(point) {
        return {
            x:point.x,
            y:point.y + point.z / 4};
    }

    // Рисуем фигуру по точкам из массива
    function fillFigure(context, arr, color) {
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        context.fillStyle = color;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            context.beginPath();
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][4] != undefined) {
                    context.fillStyle = arr[i][4];
                } else {
                    context.fillStyle = color;
                }
                if (j == 0) {
                    context.moveTo(arr[i][j].x, arr[i][j].y);
                } else {
                    context.lineTo(arr[i][j].x, arr[i][j].y);
                }
            }
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            context.stroke();
        }
        
        context.font = '12px';
       context.fillText('Рисуется сторон: ' + arr.length, -120, 20);
    }

    // Запускаем наш скрипт
    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(initAnimation, 200);
    };
```

```html
<canvas id="animation" width="300" height="300">
    <p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает Canvas</p>
</canvas>
```

Релевантный кусок:

```js
// Получаем параллельную проекцию кубика на плоскость экрана
function getParallelProjection(arr) {
    var i, j, k;

    var projected = [];
    var projection;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        projection = [];
        if (arr[i].length < 6) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                projection[j] = getPointParallelProjection(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
        projected[i] = projection;
    }

    return projected.filter(isClockwise);
}

function isClockwise(point_array) {
    if (point_array.length < 3) return false;
    var p0 = point_array[0];
    var p1 = point_array[1];
    var p2 = point_array[2];
    return (p1.x-p0.x)*(p2.y-p0.y) - (p2.x-p0.x)*(p1.y-p0.y) > 0;
}
```

Вся магия в том, что мы проверяем в том, как рисуются грани. Для этого, правда, пришлось поправить порядок задания вершин в самом начале, дабы каждая грань рисовалась по часовой стрелке. После проекции "векторным" произведением проверяется порядок спроецированных вершин, и если он оказался против часовой стрелки - этот набор вершин отбрасывается.

Бонусом на канвас выводится число граней, переданных в функцию отрисовки - чисто так, для верности расчётов.

Стоит ли говорить, что решена несколько иная задача, чем поставленная в вопросе, но код есть код :)

Answer (score 2):

Второй способ: подсказано пользователем [Дмитрий Чистик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185848/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA). Берем ближнюю вершину и отображаем 3 отходящих от нее грани. Лагов меньше, чем в первом случае, но все равно они есть.

Такой код тоже не работает.

```js
'use strict';

    // Массив с фигурами
    var figures;

    var figure_111 = {

        //╔═══╗
        //║   ║
        //╚═══╝

        figureType: 5,
        figurePositionY: 1,
        figurePositionX: 1,
        figurePositionZ: 1,
        shape: [
            [[5]]
        ],
        rotateZ: function () {
            this.shape = rotateZ(this.shape);
            this.figurePositionZ = changePosition(this.figurePositionZ);
        }
    };

    // Инициализация нашего скрипта
    // эту функцию надо будет вставить
    // в переменную window.onload
    function initAnimation() {
        figures = [
            figure_111
        ];

        // Запускаем падение
        figureStartsFalling();
    }

    // Текущая фигура
    var currentFigure;

    // Размер фигуры
    var size = 30;

    // Объект на основании фигуры
    var fallingObject;

    // Цвет фигуры
    var figureColor;

    // Центр фигуры
    var t0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('animation');
    var canvas_context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Сместим центр оси (Х) в середину поля
    canvas_context.translate(canvas.width / 2, 0);

    var doTenTimes;

    function figureStartsFalling() {
        doTenTimes = 30;
        // Переопределяем текущую фигуру
        currentFigure = figures[Math.floor(Math.random() * figures.length)];

        // Получим цвет текущей фигуры
        figureColor = 'rgb(0,200,0)';

        // Высота фигуры
        var figureHeight = currentFigure.shape.length;

        // Строим 3Д объект на основании фигуры
        fallingObject = [];
        var cube = [];
        var side = [];

        for (var y = currentFigure.shape.length - 1; y > -1; y--) {
            for (var x = 0; x < currentFigure.shape[0].length; x++) {
                for (var z = 0; z < currentFigure.shape[0][0].length; z++) {
                    // Для каждой клеточки создаем кубик с 5 гранями
                    cube = [];
                    if (currentFigure.shape[y][x][z] != 0) {
                        // Левая стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'left'}
                        ];
                        // Центральная координата, нужна для расчета удаленности по осям (X) и (Z)
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если левее чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (x > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x - 1][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Правая стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'right'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если правее чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (x + 1 < currentFigure.shape[0].length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x + 1][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Задняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'rear'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если сзади чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (z > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x][z - 1] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Передняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {m:'front'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если впереди чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (z + 1 < currentFigure.shape[0][0].length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y][x][z + 1] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Верхняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'top'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если сверху чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (y > 0
                            && currentFigure.shape[y - 1][x][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);

                        // Нижняя стенка
                        side = [
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {x:x*size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size + size},
                            {x:x*size + size, y:y*size + size - figureHeight*size, z:z*size},
                            {m:'bottom'}
                        ];
                        side[4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(side);
                        // Если снизу чтото есть, то не рисуем
                        if (y + 1 < currentFigure.shape.length
                            && currentFigure.shape[y + 1][x][z] != 0) {
                            side[5] = false;
                        }
                        cube.push(side);
                        fallingObject.push(cube);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Определим центр фигуры
        t0 = {
            y:currentFigure.shape.length / 2 * size - figureHeight*size,
            x:currentFigure.shape[0].length / 2 * size,
            z:currentFigure.shape[0][0].length / 2 * size
        };

        // Запускаем падение
        setTimeout(figureFalls, 100);
    }

    // Угол поворота, не изменяется
    var deg = 1;

    // Текущая проекция
    var arrProj;

    var tempArr;

    function figureFalls() {

        // Сначала очистим экран - закрасим белым цветом
        clearScreen(canvas, canvas_context, 'rgb(255,255,255)');

        // Изменяем положение текущей фигуры
        for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    // Повернем фигуру на угол
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeY(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeX(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    fallingObject[i][j][k] = rotateOnDegreeZ(t0, fallingObject[i][j][k]);
                    // и опустим вниз на 1px
                    fallingObject[i][j][k].y += 1;
                }
                // Пересчитаем центральную координату плоскости
                fallingObject[i][j][4] = getSidecentralCoordinate(fallingObject[i][j]);
            }
            doTenTimes -= 1;
            // Пересчитаем центральную координату кубика
            fallingObject[i][6] = getCubecentralCoordinate(fallingObject[i]);
            // Если кубик ушел слишком далеко - удаляем кубик
            if (fallingObject[i][6].y > canvas.height) {
                fallingObject.splice(i, 1);
                i -=1;
            }
        }

        // Центр фигуры тоже опускается
        t0.y += 1;

        // Сортируем кубики по удаленности от начала координат по (X) и (Z)
        var exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            exit = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length - 1; i++) {
                if (fallingObject[i][6].z > fallingObject[i + 1][6].z) {
                    tempArr = fallingObject[i];
                    fallingObject[i] = fallingObject[i + 1];
                    fallingObject[i + 1] = tempArr;
                    exit = false;
                } else if (fallingObject[i][6].z == fallingObject[i + 1][6].z) {
                    if (fallingObject[i][6].x > fallingObject[i + 1][6].x) {
                        tempArr = fallingObject[i];
                        fallingObject[i] = fallingObject[i + 1];
                        fallingObject[i + 1] = tempArr;
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Отрисовываем фигуру
        for (var i = 0; i < fallingObject.length; i++) {
            // Получим параллельную проекцию
            arrProj = getParallelProjection(fallingObject[i]);
            // Нарисуем параллельную проекцию
            fillFigure(canvas_context, arrProj, figureColor);
        }

        // Если в видимой области еще есть кубики -
        // переходим на следующий шаг
        if (fallingObject.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(figureFalls, 100);
        }
        // иначе начинаем заново с новой фигурой
        else {
            setTimeout(figureStartsFalling, 100);
        }
    }

    // Получим центральную координату плоскости
    // для расчета удаленности от задней стенки
    function getSidecentralCoordinate(side) {

        var centralCoordinate = {x:0, y:0, z:0};

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            centralCoordinate.x += side[i].x;
            centralCoordinate.y += side[i].y;
            centralCoordinate.z += side[i].z;
        }

        centralCoordinate.x = centralCoordinate.x / 4;
        centralCoordinate.y = centralCoordinate.y / 4;
        centralCoordinate.z = centralCoordinate.z / 4;

        centralCoordinate.m = side[4].m;

        return centralCoordinate;
    }

    // Получим центральную координату кубика
    // для расчета удаленности от начала координат
    function getCubecentralCoordinate(side) {
        var centralCoordinate = {x:0, y:0, z:0};

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            centralCoordinate.x += side[i][4].x;
            centralCoordinate.y += side[i][4].y;
            centralCoordinate.z += side[i][4].z;
        }

        centralCoordinate.x = centralCoordinate.x / 6;
        centralCoordinate.y = centralCoordinate.y / 6;
        centralCoordinate.z = centralCoordinate.z / 6;

        return centralCoordinate;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (Y)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeY(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t0.x + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.z - t0.z) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.y = t.y;
        t_new.z = t0.z + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.z - t0.z) * Math.cos(rad);

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (X)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeX(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t.x;
        t_new.y = t0.y + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.z - t0.z) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.z = t0.z + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.z - t0.z) * Math.cos(rad);

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Поворачиваем точку t(x,y,z) на угол (deg) по оси (Z)
    // относительно точки t0(x,y,z)
    function rotateOnDegreeZ(t0, t) {

        var t_new = {};

        // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
        var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;

        // Рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
        t_new.x = t0.x + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.y - t0.y) * Math.sin(rad);
        t_new.y = t0.y + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.cos(rad);
        t_new.z = t.z;

        // Возвращаем полученное значение
        return t_new;
    }

    // Закрашиваем весь экран определенным цветом
    function clearScreen(canvas, context, color) {
        context.fillStyle = color;

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillRect(- canvas.width / 2, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    // Получаем параллельную проекцию кубика на плоскость экрана
    function getParallelProjection(arr) {

        var i, j, k;

        var arr_new = [];

        // Найдем ближнюю по оси (Z) вершину
        var point = {x:-10000, y:10000, z:-10000};
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j].z > point.z) {
                    point = arr[i][j];
                }
                if (arr[i][j].z == point.z
                    && arr[i][j].x > point.x) {
                    point = arr[i][j];
                }
                if (arr[i][j].z == point.z
                    && arr[i][j].x == point.x
                    && arr[i][j].y < point.y) {
                    point = arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        // Упорядочим грани по удаленности от ближней вершины
        var exit, temp;
        do {
            exit = true;
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (findDistance(point, arr[i][4]) > findDistance(point, arr[i + 1][4])) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = temp;
                    exit = false;
                }
            }
        } while (!exit);

        var projection;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            projection = [];
            if (arr[i].length < 6) {
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    projection[j] = getPointParallelProjection(arr[i][j]);
                }
            }
            arr_new[i] = projection;
        }

        return arr_new;
    }

    // Находим расстояние между двумя точками в пространстве
    function findDistance(point1, point2) {
        return Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow((point2.x - point1.x), 2)
            + Math.pow((point2.y - point1.y), 2)
            + Math.pow((point2.z - point1.z), 2)
        )
    }
    
    // Параллельная проекция точки
    function getPointParallelProjection(point) {
        return {
            x:point.x,
            y:point.y + point.z / 4};
    }

    // Рисуем фигуру по точкам из массива
    function fillFigure(context, arr, color) {
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        context.fillStyle = color;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            context.beginPath();
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][4] != undefined) {
                    context.fillStyle = arr[i][4];
                } else {
                    context.fillStyle = color;
                }
                if (j == 0) {
                    context.moveTo(arr[i][j].x, arr[i][j].y);
                } else {
                    context.lineTo(arr[i][j].x, arr[i][j].y);
                }
            }
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    // Запускаем наш скрипт
    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(initAnimation, 200);
    };
```

```html
<canvas id="animation" width="300" height="300">
    <p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает Canvas</p>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

В чем собственно сложность?

1. Преобразуете все вершины
2. Вычисляете центры граней
3. Берете три ближних

---

Или даже еще проще:

1. Берете центры граней
2. Преобразуете центры граней согласно проекции
3. Берете три ближних

Comment: а не верно ли будет брать три грани отходящей от ближней угловой точки?